# iOS admob never refresh ad

Tags: ios, admob, adbannerview

I recently published my app with iAd and Admob, and I followed every instruction to set up Admob correctly. But I soon realize that Admob ad won't ever refresh -- it only shows one ad no matter what (restart app, re-install app, and etc). I set up auto refresh rate at 30sec on Admob website. Is there a method to refresh it programmatically?

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: All codes I used were from their official site, nothing special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this module and seems to work just fine:

https://github.com/shad/titanium_modules/tree/master/admob

Have a one thing in mind that the ads might be the same, even when refreshing, especially if you don't enable google ads in the Admob console.
So please enable it in Admob console.

[image]
Hope it helps you !